# How can I plot an indicator with a condition that RSI must be greater than x but less than y in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to plot an indicator with an rsi value from 52 to 80 only but whenever I put a range format below:

```
rsiup = 50 < rsi < 80
rsidown = 30 < rsi < 50
```

then I get this error:

```
Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr0'='call 'operator <' (series bool)'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'const float' is expected
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break it down into two `and` conditions.

```
rsiup = (50 < rsi) and (rsi < 80)
rsidown = (30 < rsi) and (rsi < 50)
```